# Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong with Android

Tags: android, here-api, signature, heremaps-android-sdk, hmacsha256

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/identity-and-access-management-developer-guide/page/topics/sdk.html) to fetch the auth token for the HERE maps. I am able to fetch the token with my iOS app, However I cannot seem to get the token with Android. I keep getting the error `errorCode: '401300'. Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong."`

Below is my code to fetch the token :

**HEREOAuthManager.java**

```html
public void fetchOAuthToken(final HereTokenFetchListener callback) {
        String timestamp = String.valueOf(String.valueOf(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()));
        String nonce = Util.randomStringGenerator();
        String grant_type = "grant_type=client_credentials";
        String oauth_consumer_key = "&oauth_consumer_key=" + clientID   ;
        String oauth_nonce = "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce;
        String oauth_signature_method = "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256";
        String oauth_timestamp = "&oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp;
        String oauth_version = "&oauth_version=1.0";

        String paramsString = grant_type + oauth_consumer_key + oauth_nonce + oauth_signature_method + oauth_timestamp + oauth_version;
        String baseString = "POST&" + Util.urlEncode(tokenEndpoint) + "&" + Util.urlEncode(paramsString);



        // Generate signature
        String secret = Util.urlEncode(clientSecret) + "&";
    String signature = Util.calculateHmacSha256(secret, baseString);

                // Construct Authorization header
        String authString = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + clientID + "\",oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce +
                "\",oauth_signature=\"" + Util.urlEncode(signature) + "\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\"," +
                "oauth_timestamp=\"" + timestamp + "\",oauth_version=\"1.0\"";

        // Create HTTP client
      OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        // Create request body
        RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .build();

//        // Create HTTP request
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(tokenEndpoint)
                .post(requestBody)
                .addHeader("Authorization", authString)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .build();
}
```

**Utils.java**

```html
public static String calculateHmacSha256(String secret, String data) {
        try {
            String secretWithAmpersand = secret + "&";
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "HmacSHA256");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
            byte[] hmacData = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String baseEncodedSignature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacData);
            return urlEncode(baseEncodedSignature);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String urlEncode(String stringToEncode) {
        try {
            return java.net.URLEncoder.encode(stringToEncode, "UTF-8")
                    .replace("+", "%20") // Replace '+' with '%20'
                    .replace("=", "%3D")
                    .replace("*", "%2A") // Replace '*' with '%2A'
                    .replace("&", "%26")
                    .replace( "~","%7E"); // Replace '~' with '%7E';
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static String randomStringGenerator()
    {
        String ALLOWED_CHARACTERS ="0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
        final Random random=new Random();
        final StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(8);
        for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
            sb.append(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.charAt(random.nextInt(ALLOWED_CHARACTERS.length())));
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

What could I be missing? Any help is appreciated